# Installing addmtoolbox on Windows : x is not a data.table (RStudio)

Tags: r

I'm trying to install addmtoolbox on Rstudio. every things is fine but at last i got this error:

```
Error: Vignette re-building failed.
Execution halted
Error: Failed to install 'addmtoolbox' from GitHub:
  System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr (last 10 lines):
E> Quitting from lines 80-84 (addmtoolbox_modelfit_walkthrough.Rmd) 
E> Error: processing vignette 'addmtoolbox_modelfit_walkthrough.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
E> x is not a data.table
E> --- failed re-building 'addmtoolbox_modelfit_walkthrough.Rmd'
E> 
E> SUMMARY: processing the following file failed:
E>   'addmtoolbox_modelfit_walkthrough.Rmd'
E> 
E> Error: Vignette re-building failed.
E> Execution halted
```

also i'm trying to install package from zip file. installation is successful but when i run addm_preprocess function,
i got same error:

```
>  my.dat = addm_preprocess(choice.dat = addm_data_choice,
+                         eye.dat = addm_data_eye,
+                         timestep = 10,
+                         rtbinsize = 100) 
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  x is not a data.table
```

would you please help me?
thanks.

addmtoolbox:
https://rdrr.io/github/AlexanderFengler/addmtoolbox/

EDIT:
i found error code:

```
eye$fixdur =  timestep * round(eye$fixdur/timestep)
  rts = eye %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(rt = sum(fixdur))
  setkey(rts,id)
  choice = choice %>% select(-rt)
  choice = choice[rts]
```

setkey(rts,id) return error:

```
> rts
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     id    rt
* <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0
>   setkey(rts,id)
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  x is not a data.table
```

Comment: It looks like you're providing a `tibble` when a `data.table` is expected. You should be able to convert the object with `as.data.table`. Alternatively you could also use `dtyplyr` for unified tibble/data.table objects. https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr

Comment: thanks. with "as.data.table" my problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution by : [hdkrgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4755970/hdkrgr)

> It looks like you're providing a tibble when a data.table is expected.
> You should be able to convert the object with as.data.table.
> Alternatively you could also use dtyplyr for unified tibble/data.table
> objects. github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr